# How to load kernel module after providing invalid parameter at boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, kernel-module, centos7

Long story short, I am on Centos7 and want to avoid loading a kernel module before it has been replaced by another. I am netbooting from an image I cant change atm. so I cant make any modifications except kernel params really.

I have tried "modprobe.blacklist=kernelmodule" but it doesn't seem to do what I want. If I blacklist a module that is usually loaded at boot, it's still loaded even though "modprobe --show-config | grep black" shows it as blacklisted.

I found another way though. If I provide an invalid parameter at boot the module is not loaded. E.g. if I give "kernelmodule.blabla=yes" as a kernel boot parameter. But this way the module can't even be loaded with modprobe after boot since it has an invalid parameter. Is there any way to make the kernel forget about the parameter ? Or maybe there is a better way ?

Comment: Have you tried using insmod on that module instead of modprobe?

Comment: Parameters are shared under `/sys/module/<module>/parameters/<parameter>`, you may change them at any time, though not all modules cope with that and take the updated values into consideration. And of course you may unbind or bind any module even if it's compiled in.

Comment: The module does not seem to show up in /sys/modules/ before its been loaded. I was able to insmod it though. Can't believe I didn't think of that myself - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter L. stated it seems that insmod can be used to avoid the kernel forcing any parameters.